How to customize(learn) Google V3 AutoML, and then connect RWS Studio 2022?
We couldn't connect V3(Jason file) to RWS Studio.
So, we would like to know step by step how to learn Google V3 AutoML, then connect RWS studio 2022.
We are planning to test Korean to English translation using on Google V3 AutoML.
Please help us.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
